# can I reset the hidden state of an RNN between input data sets in Keras?

Tags: hidden, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am training an RNN on a large data set which consists of disparate sources. I do not want the history of one set to spill over to the next. This means I want to reset the hidden state at the end of one set, before sending in the next. How can I do that with Keras? The doc claims you can get into the low level configurations.

What I am trying to do is resetting the lstm hidden state every time a new data set is fed, so no influence from the prev dataset is carried forward. see line

```
prevh = Hout[t-1] if t > 0 else h0
```

from Karpathy's simple python implementation
https://gist.github.com/karpathy/587454dc0146a6ae21fc
line 45

If I find the lstm layer and call reset on it, I am worried that would wipe out the entire training of the weights and biases, not just Hout

Here is the training loop code

```
for iteration in range(1, 10):
    for key in X_dict:
        X = X_dict[key]
        y = y_dict[key]
        history=model.fit(X, y, batch_size=batch_size, callbacks=cbks, nb_epoch=1,verbose=0)
```

Each turn in the loop feeds in data from a single market. That's where I like to reset the hout in the lstm.

Comment: Why would you want to reset the hidden state this is where the learning of latent features occurs?

Answer (score 2):

> To reset the states of your model, call `.reset_states()` on either a specific layer, or on your entire model. [source](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/)

So if you have a list of datasets :

```
for ds in datasets :
    model.reset_states()
    model.fit(ds['inputs'],ds['targets'],...)
```

Is that what you are looking for?

**EDIT :**

```
for iteration in range(1, 10):
    for key in X_dict:
        model.reset_states() # reset the states of all the LSTM's of your network
        #model.layers[lstm_layer_index].reset_states() # reset the states of this specific LSTM layer
        X = X_dict[key]
        y = y_dict[key]
        history=model.fit(X, y, batch_size=batch_size, callbacks=cbks, nb_epoch=1,verbose=0)
```

This is how you apply it.

By default, the LSTM's are not stateful. Which means that they won't keep a hidden state after going over a sequence. The initial state when starting a new sequence will be set to 0. If you selected `stateful=True`, then it will keep the last hidden state (the output) of the previous sequence to initialize itself for the next sequence in the batch. It's like the sequence was continuing.

Doing `model.reset_states()` will just reset those last hidden states that were kept in memory to 0, just like if the sequence was starting from scratch.

If you don't trust that `.reset_states()` to do what you expect, feel free to go to the source code.

Comment: I am having a hard time finding out how to reset a single layer. If you could put down some more code on it. I explained further in my post exactly what I am trying to reset.

Comment: I tried model.layers[0].reset_states(). It says Layer must be stateful. layers[0]  is an lstm layer.

Comment: Please show your code, I need to see what you currently do and I will show you how you can do what you want. Are you feeding your network by batch? You want the hidden state to be reset to 0 after each sample or after a big bunch of samples/batches ?

Comment: Let me explain in words first. reset after a big bunch of batches. I am in a loop, this reset should occur at the top of each loop.

Comment: Alright, then show me that loop and where you want the reset and I'll adapt my answer, good for you?

Comment: The loop code is shown. Not sure why it helps with the answer. I hope it does.

Comment: Oh, very nice. Let me try that.